# Android 3.0 WebView crashes 

Tags: android, flash, webview, crash, android-3.0-honeycomb

Hi im trying to build a webview with flash for android 3.0 API 11, ive been searching for days now for a solution but could find anything useful, I dont know where the problem is.. ? IT CRASHS ON THE EMULATOR WHEN I START IT! PLEASE HELP! :(

**erorr code**

```
03-26 00:26:47.747: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(637): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-26 00:26:47.747: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(637): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{xxxxx.com.xxxxx/xxxxx.com.xxxxx.xxxxxctivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: xxxxxx.com.xxxxx.xxxxxActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/xxxxxx.com.xxxxxxvol-2.apk]
03-26 00:26:47.747: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(637):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1660)
03-26 00:26:47.747: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(637):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1752)
03-26 00:26:47.747: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(637):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
03-26 00:26:47.747: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(637):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:993)
03-26 00:26:47.747: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(637):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-26 00:26:47.747: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(637):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
03-26 00:26:47.747: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(637):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
03-26 00:26:47.747: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(637):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-26 00:26:47.747: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(637):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
03-26 00:26:47.747: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(637):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
03-26 00:26:47.747: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(637):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
03-26 00:26:47.747: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(637):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-26 00:26:47.747: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(637): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: xxxxx.com.xxxxx.xxxxxxctivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/xxxxxxx.com.xxxxxxxx-2.apk]
03-26 00:26:47.747: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(637):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:251)
03-26 00:26:47.747: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(637):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:548)
03-26 00:26:47.747: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(637):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:508)
03-26 00:26:47.747: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(637):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1022)
03-26 00:26:47.747: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(637):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
03-26 00:26:47.747: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(637):     ... 11 more
```

**JAVA CODE**

```
package xxxxx.com.xxxxx;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;

import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdView;


public class DemoriginalActivity extends Activity {
private static final String WebSettings = null;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private WebView webview;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

AdView adview = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.ad);

AdRequest re = new AdRequest();
re.setTesting(true);
adview.loadAd(re);

webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);

// workaround so that the default browser doesn't take over
//Compile error: MyWebViewClient cannot be resolved to a type
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);

webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.loadUrl("http://google.com/"); 

}



public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webview.canGoBack()) {
        webview.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}



public static String getWebsettings() {
    return WebSettings;
}
}
```

**MAIN XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    >

    <WebView android:id="@+id/webview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text = "Hello, world!"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        />            


<RelativeLayout
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <com.google.ads.AdView
     ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxx"
     ads:adSize="BANNER"
     android:id="@+id/ad"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
     </RelativeLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an activity listed in your manifest (`xxxxx.com.xxxxx.xxxxxxctivity`) that you are trying to start, but this class does not exist in your project.

Comment: and it's probably a typo to the real class name, check your spellings will prob resolve the issue.

Comment: nono i typed xxxxx insted of my real activity... sorry for that but its app privacy. anyway do you find anything wrong without that ?? : (